# Calculating Percentile scores for each element with respect to its column

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

So my NumPy array looks like this

```
npfinal = 
    [[1, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0],
    [5, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0],
    [7, 7, 2, 0, 0, 0],
    .
    .
    .
```

Sample dataset I'm working with is 25k rows.

The first 3 columns contain meaningful data, rest are placeholders for the percentiles.

So I need the percentile of a[0][0] **with respect to the entire first column** in a[0][3]. So 1's percentile score wrt the column [1,5,7,...]

My first attempt was:

```
import scipy.stats as ss
...
numofcols = 3
for row in npfinal:
    for i in range(0,numofcols):
        row[i+numofcols] = int(round(ss.percentileofscore(npfinal[:,i], row[i])))
```

But this is taking way too much time; and on a full dataset it'll be impossible.

I'm new to the world of computing on such large datasets so any sort of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that I believe it works better when there are repeated values in the array:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

# some array with repeated values:
M = np.array([[1, 7, 2], [5, 2, 2], [5, 7, 2]])    

# calculate percentiles applying scipy rankdata to each column:
percentile = np.apply_along_axis(sp.stats.rankdata, 0, M, method='average')/len(M)
```

The np.argsort solution has the problem that it gives different percentiles to repetitions of the same value. For example if you had:

```
percentile_argsort = np.argsort(np.argsort(M, axis=0), axis=0) / float(len(M)) * 100
percentile_rankdata = np.apply_along_axis(sp.stats.rankdata, 0, M, method='average')/len(M)
```

the two different approaches will output the results:

```
M
array([[1, 7, 2],
       [5, 2, 2],
       [5, 7, 2]])
percentile_argsort
array([[  0.        ,  33.33333333,   0.        ],
       [ 33.33333333,   0.        ,  33.33333333],
       [ 66.66666667,  66.66666667,  66.66666667]])
percentile_rankdata
array([[ 0.33333333,  0.83333333,  0.66666667],
       [ 0.83333333,  0.33333333,  0.66666667],
       [ 0.83333333,  0.83333333,  0.66666667]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to compute the percentile by sorting the array and dividing the resulting index by the total number of rows (assuming NumPy is available):

```py
import numpy as np

M = np.array([[1, 3, 5], [5, 2, 4], [7, 7, 2]])

percentile = np.argsort(np.argsort(M, axis=0), axis=0) / float(len(M)) * 100

print "M:\n", M
print "percentile:\n", percentile
```

Output:

```
M:
[[1 3 5]
 [5 2 4]
 [7 7 2]]
percentile:
[[  0.          33.33333333  66.66666667]
 [ 33.33333333   0.          33.33333333]
 [ 66.66666667  66.66666667   0.        ]]
```

Now you only need to concatenate the result and your original array.

Comment: Shouldn't it actually be `nppercentile = np.argsort(np.argsort(npfinal, axis =0), axis=0) / float(len(npfinal)) * 100` ?

Comment: Oh, I guess you are right! ```b=argsort(a)``` does not yield the positions, where the elements of ```a``` *should* be when sorted; but each value in ```b``` refers to an *original* position in ```a```... Confusing. I'll update my answer.